# Why does "let" sometimes exit when run with bash -e?

Tags: linux, bash

The content of a.sh is

```
echo start
let index=(RANDOM % 4)
echo $index
```

a.sh sometimes fails to produce the number

```
gqqnbig@instance-1:~/test/systemd$ vim a.sh
gqqnbig@instance-1:~/test/systemd$ bash -e a.sh
start
3
gqqnbig@instance-1:~/test/systemd$ bash -e a.sh
start
3
gqqnbig@instance-1:~/test/systemd$ bash -e a.sh
start
2
gqqnbig@instance-1:~/test/systemd$ bash -e a.sh
start
2
gqqnbig@instance-1:~/test/systemd$ bash -e a.sh
start
2
gqqnbig@instance-1:~/test/systemd$ bash -e a.sh
start
3
gqqnbig@instance-1:~/test/systemd$ bash -e a.sh
start
3
gqqnbig@instance-1:~/test/systemd$ bash -e a.sh
start
gqqnbig@instance-1:~/test/systemd$ echo $?
1
gqqnbig@instance-1:~/test/systemd$
```

See the last time I run a.sh, it only outputs "start" but not the index, which means `let index=(RANDOM % 4)` has something wrong, and the exit code is 1.

Why does the RANDOM variable produce this random error? How do I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you use `let index=($RANDOM % 4)`?

Comment: Nevermind, I observe the same behavior with both combinations.
A simple test to trigger: `for i in {1..10}; do { let test=($RANDOM % 4) && echo $test; } || break; done`. It will try 10 times (enough to fail for sure in my case), breaks at first failure.

Comment: It doesn't fail if using traditional arithmetic expansion instead of `let`.

Comment: Fun thing: `let test=(0 % 4)` always fails. Maybe that's where we should start looking? I tend to think there's something wrong with the usage rather than bugs, but I'm not sure how to dig the documentation, and it seems counter intuitive.

Comment: @Oppen have you read the posted answer yet?

Comment: Even funnier: whenever the result of the modulus is `0`, it reports failure. It does assign the result, though.

Comment: Oops, failed to refresh. Thanks.

Comment: See the exercises in [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises), regarding the myriad of ways `bash -e` makes your code less predictable, less portable, more contextually-dependent, and harder to reliably review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `-e` causes `bash` to terminate on error.

When `let` evaluates to `0`, it is considered an error.  Bash will terminate the script before printing the value `0`.

---

To avoid undesired termination you can use one of the following approaches:

1. Don't use the `-e` flag
2. Ensure the statement always succeeds:

```
let 'index=(RANDOM % 4)' || true
```

or

```
let 'index=(RANDOM % 4)' || :
```

3. Avoid using `let` (per @LéaGris):

```
index=$((RANDOM % 4))
```

Comment: To protect the arithmetic expression from returning failure, use this form instead: `bash -ec 'for i in {1..10}; do { test=$((RANDOM % 4)); echo $test; } || break; done'`

Comment: I failed to state that I understand the implication of `-e` flag, but I have no authority to remove this flag. It's the default flag in GitHub Actions, they do this for a reason. But thanks so much for the explanation of `let`.